# Javascrpt style give me problems

Tags: javascript

VS code gives me an error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'style') at HTMLButtonElement.acc

```js
function acc() {

  if (button.style.display == 'none') {
    button.style.display = 'block';
    var button = document.createElement('button');
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    var img = document.createElement('img');
    var h4 = document.createElement('h4');

    div.appendChild(button);
    div.appendChild(img);
    div.appendChild(h4);

    h4.style.color = 'red';
    h4 = 'Account';

    button.innerHTML = h4;
    div.classList.add('achi');

    document.getElementById('achi').appendChild(div);

  } else {
    button.style.display = 'none';
  }

}

let accBtn = document.getElementById('acc-btn');
accBtn.addEventListener('click', acc);
```

Comment: `button` is clearly undefined. But without you showing us how you are defining that variable's value, and most likely what's in your HTML as well, it's impossible to say why it's `undefined`.

Comment: Suggestion:  don't define variables with the same name.  It's asking for confusion and errors.

Comment: Why put `var button` after `button.style.display`?

Answer (score 0):

1. You don't need an `if` check for the styles of an element you just created. You define the styles of your brand new element.
2. You define a variable named `h4` and set it to point to an element, then redefine it later on to equal a string. Weird. Don't do that.
3. You can't access `button` before it's been defined. It is `undefined` up until that point.
4. The `<h4>` tag is empty. Do you want that?
5. Don't use `innerHTML` to just set text content. Use `textContent` or `innerText` instead (`innerText` keeps the newlines).

Refactored:

```
const accBtn = document.getElementById('acc-btn');

function acc() {
    const div = document.createElement('div');
    div.classList.add('achi');

    const button = document.createElement('button');
    button.style.display = 'block';
    button.textContent = 'Account'

    const img = document.createElement('img');

    const h4 = document.createElement('h4');
    h4.style.color = 'red';

    div.appendChild(button);
    div.appendChild(img);
    div.appendChild(h4);

    document.getElementById('achi').appendChild(div);
}

accBtn.addEventListener('click', acc);
```